# How to set a default value in field from another field in doctrine migration?

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-migrations

I have an application in symfony 1.4. I use doctrine migration to modify my database and my entity. But I want to know if it's possible when I add a column to my table to set the default value (for this new column) from another field who located in another table ?

This is an exemple of a file I use to make the doctrine migration:

```
    class Competence extends Doctrine_Migration_Base
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('competence', 'rayon_competence', 'integer', '11', array('default'=>'50'));
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->removeColumn('competence', 'rayon_competence');
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear else I can explain ;). If someone have an idea or can help me it would be great ! Thank in advance !